WOT compactness of some special set
Let $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$ be the algebra of bounded linear maps on Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$. Consider the following set
$$\mathcal{S}=\left\{B\in\mathcal{B(\mathcal{H})}: BB^*+B^*B=I\right\}.$$
Is $\mathcal{S}$ weak-operator topology (WOT) compact in $\mathcal{B\mathcal{(H)}}$?
Comments: I can see that every sequence in $\mathcal{S}$ has a WOT limit in $\mathcal{B(\mathcal{H})}$, but it is not clear to me why the limit belongs to $\mathcal{S}$.

It's not. Let $\mathbb{N}$ be the set of positive integers, $H = \ell^2(\mathbb{N})$. For each $n \geq 2$, fix a bijection $\pi_n: \mathbb{N} \setminus n\mathbb{N} \to n\mathbb{N}$. Then let $S_n \in B(H)$ be defined by,
$$S_n(e_m) = \begin{cases}
e_{\pi_n(m)} &, \text{ if }m \in \mathbb{N} \setminus n\mathbb{N}\\
0 &, \text{ if }m \in n\mathbb{N}
\end{cases}$$
Then $S_n \in \mathcal{S}$ for all $n \geq 2$, but $S_n \to 0$ in WOT and $0 \notin \mathcal{S}$.

Thank you for your response. I have a small doubt. Take $n=3$ and $\pi_3(m)=3m, m\in\mathbb{N}\setminus 3\mathbb{N}$. I think $S_3\notin\mathcal{S}$, because $S_3S_3^*+S_3^*S_3$ takes $e_9$ to 0. Sorry, if I misunderstood your map.

@Piku $\pi_n$ has to be a bijection. Your $\pi_3$ is not - $9$ is not in the range (which is exactly why $S_3S_3^\ast + S_3^\ast S_3$ sends $e_9$ to $0$ in your case).

Got it, thanks!

Btw, just an additional observation: $\mathcal{S}$ is not even SOT-closed, since $S_n^\ast \to 0$ in SOT. Though it is not hard to check $\mathcal{S}$ is strong$^\ast$ closed.

It would have been great if you kindly elaborate the fact that $\mathcal{S}$ is strong*-closed.

@Piku All elements of $\mathcal{S}$ have norm at most $1$. Taking adjoints is strong$^\ast$-continuous and multiplication is strong$^\ast$-continuous on bounded sets. $\mathcal{S}$ being strong$^\ast$-closed then easily follows.
